# Implement a sql query to ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have googled,for along time in order to find solution to implement a sql server query to ssis

```
SELECT
    Sales_Order_Number,company_code,isnull(
    (
        SELECT
            distinct Description + ';' AS 'text()'
        FROM
            dbo.l_Fact_Orders as xml
            INNER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Dim_ItemSOA items ON items.Item_SOA_ID=xml.Item_SOA_ID
        WHERE
            xml.Sales_Order_Number = myTable.Sales_Order_Number
            and xml.company_code = myTable.company_code 
        FOR
            XML PATH('')
    )
    ,'') as Description
FROM
    dbo.l_Fact_Orders myTable
GROUP BY
    Sales_Order_Number,company_code
```

I am looking for ideas please.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please provide more information about what the actual problem is and what you've tried so far...

Comment: If all you want to do is have that query executed inside of an SSIS package, you can put the query into an `Execute SQL` task.

Answer (score 1):

It is bit unclear what you want to do with this query, but I believe that you want to simply get the columns from the query and do something with them?

1. Drag a "Data Flow Task" to your package
2. Open the Data Flow, add "OLE DB Source" and click on it
3. If you haven't created OLE DB connection before, click "New" near the connection manager, otherwise select the connection from the dropdown list
4. In "Data access mode" select "SQL Command"
5. Paste your command below

[image]